# Custom Message or paragraph from the using Jquery datatable and pdf export

Tags: pdf, datatables

I'm using the pdf button from jquery datatables which is essentially the pdfmake library. The problem that I'm having is that I would like to add an additional paragraph right above my table when the user clicks the button to export the table. I have tried using the "message" parameter but for the life of me I cannot retrieve additional information right before the pdf will download. I tried doing this.

```js
buttons: [
                       {
                           extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                           orientation: 'landscape',
                           pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                           title: 'Entry',
                           header:true,
                           message:function() { $("#HeaderDesc").text()}

                       }
]
```

But I have been unsuccessful in my attempts. Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. The `config` literal for the button is read *once*, and `message` does not support function type.

However, you can change the `message` in the not so well documented `customize()` callback. This is called just before dataTables pass the generated document to pdfmake. If you have defined a `message`, then there will exists `message` section(s) in the `content` nodes, and those nodes have a `text` attribute holding the actual message  :

```js
customize: function ( doc ) {
   doc.content.forEach(function(content) {
     if (content.style == 'message') {
        content.text = 'this is a late created message'
     }
   })
}
```

As mentioned, you *must* define `message` before this will work. If you have not defined `message`, there will be no styles of type message you can manipulate. Your `pdfhtml5` settings could look like this :

```js
buttons: [
   {
    message: '__MESSAGE__',
    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
    orientation: 'landscape',
    pageSize: 'LEGAL',
    title: 'Entry',
    header:true,
    customize: function ( doc ) {
       doc.content.forEach(function(content) {
         if (content.style == 'message') {
            content.text = $("#HeaderDesc").text()
         }
       })
    }   
 }  
]
```

demo -> **https://jsfiddle.net/xx5f5z6x/**

Comment: you are the best! thank you so much for answering. I was racking my brain about that customize callback.

Answer (score 4):

There is another easy solution to this.
I accomplished this by using splice property. You can do like this inside customize function.

```
 doc.content.splice(0, 1, {
                            text: [
                                       { text: 'I am loving dataTable and PdfMake \n',bold:true,fontSize:15 },
                                       { text: 'You can control everything.',italics:true,fontSize:12 }

                            ],
                            margin: [0, 0, 0, 12],
                            alignment: 'center'
                        });
```

This will splice at the first position [0 index] as well as replace 1 value with the above content.

Happy coding!!!!